# Give examples when the Mean Value Theorem for integrals fails (One dimension)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

MVT for integrals in one dimension is: if S is a compact, connected, measurable set in R, and f,g is continuous on S and g(x)>0 for $x\in S$, then $\exists x\in S$ s.t. $f(c)=\frac{\int _{S}f(x)g(x)dx}{\int _{S}g(x)dx}$.

Now consider the following case:
1)S=(0,1]
2)S=(-2,-1)$\cup $(1,2)

In each case, construct a $f$ and $g$ that satisfy the assumptions of the theorem but fail the conclusion.

My effort: In case 1, I tried to consider f(x) as $sin(2\pi x)$ and g(x) as 1, but it turns out x=1 satisfy the conclusion. Could someone give me some hint on how to find such f(x) and g(x)? Thanks!

Comment: I think it is $\exists c$

Comment: The case 2) is very simple: take $g(x)=1$ and $f(x)=-1$ on $(-2,-1)$, $f(x)=1$ on $(1,2)$

Comment: I think for 1) you need an unbounded function, but I'm not absolutely sure.

Comment: 1) can **only** fail if $f$ is unbounded. In general, the value of the integral above must lie in $[\inf f(S), \sup f(S)]$ and it can only attain the extreme values if $f$ is essentially constant.

Comment: Yeah, I thought so, I just wasn't 100% sure. But I suppose if $f$ is bounded then the integrals on $(0,1]$ and $[0,1]$ are the same, aren't they?

Comment: @alex: Actually, I didn't consider the case where $g$ might have $\int g = \infty$, so my statement above is incorrect.

Comment: @copper.hat Then $\int_S fg$ has to be finite for the fraction to have any meaning, and $f$ might not take value $0$, is that what you mean?

Comment: @alex: Yes, that was my thinking, something like $g(x) = {1 \over x}  $ and $f(x) = x$, so the fraction is zero, but $f$ is non-zero on $(0,1)$.

Comment: @copper.hat I had thought exactly the same example... The only point is whether we accept the denominator being infinite or not. I don't see objections to it.

Comment: @alex: I think that if infinities are not allowed, then the statement is valid for 1).

Comment: I've tried examples mentioned by Cooper for 1),i.e.  f=x and g=1/x, it's correct. Thanks!

Comment: I still have a question though. Suppose S is $(1,\infty )$. If $f \mapsto \infty $, and the fraction also goes to infinity. Can we say that we can't find a $c\in S$ which satisfies the conclusion?

Answer (score 1):

1) $f=1/x$, $g=1$.

2) $f(x)=x$, $g(x)=1$.

Comment: I don't see why 1) should fail the conclusion.

Comment: Does your first suggestion really give a counter example? I see $0=0$ as the conclusion.

Comment: Yes, my first example was wrong, thanks. I'll try to find one different from copper hat's.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Examine a proof of the theorem to see where it fails if various hypothesis of the theorem are not satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

For 1), take $f(x) = {1 \over x}$, $g(x) = 1$. Then the integral is infinite, but $f$ is finite on $(0,1]$.

For 2), take $f = 1_{(1,2)}$, $g(x) = 1$, then the integral evaluates to ${1 \over 2}$, but $f$ only takes values $\{0,1\}$.